# WixCode Opting out of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, velo

Can anybody help me to find a solution how to make this code work on my Wix-Site:

```
    <a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Click here to opt-out of Google Analytics</a>
```

I have this code from Google itself (At the bottom of the page see "example"):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/

Here is a Screenshot of this code from the google website:
[Google Analytics Opt Out Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKDJo.jpg)

I tried this:

```
    $w("#text1").html = "<a href='javascript:gaOptout()'>Click here to opt-out of Google Analytics</a>";
```

But I was told that in Wix it is not possible to add events to a-tag elements in text element. Here you will find the little discussion that I had on Wix Forum: 
https://www.wix.com/code/home/forum/questions-answers/how-to-link-text-to-a-url-using-w-link

I also asked on Reddit, Facebook and WixSupport. But nobody could help me with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the new wix feature called "tracking and analytics". It lets you embed custom scripts in your html's body, header, or footer.

https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-tracking-tools-analytics

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the HTML directly via Wix Code. Wix Code exposes a dedicated API for you to manipulate their controllers and elements on screen but not further under the hood.

You can use `wix-fetch` to call external API calls to **google analytics**
 (if they have an API to `opt-out`, not familiar enough to say here is the post)

anyway, your code in **Wix** should be something like this:

(as example API taken from their [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics))

```js
import {fetch} from 'wix-data'


fetch('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/...', options) // returns a Promise
```